# Positional parameter binding with values starting with a minus/hyphen

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

Here is my PowerShell test script:

```psh
param( 
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
              Position=0)]
   [int]$val
)
Write-Output $val;
```

Now I want to call it like this:

```
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\testscript.ps1" "-1"
```

The error I get is:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name '1'.

Note that I have no control over the way the application calls my script (i.e. I can not make the application call my script with `-val:-1`). So binding has to be positional. How can I make my script bind `-1` to `$val` with the `param` block?

Comment: The only way I can think of is with explicit parameter declaration: `"-val:-1"`, but that doesn't help if it has to be positional

Answer (score 3):

If you can't fix how the application calls the script the only other option I see is to drop the named parameters entirely and use the `$args` collection instead:

```
C:\>type test.ps1
[int]$val = $args[0]
Write-Output $val

C:\>powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File test.ps1 -1
-1
```

By casting the argument to `[int]` type safety is still enforced:

```
C:\>powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File test.ps1 a
Cannot convert value "a" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not
in a correct format."
At C:\Users\cobalt\Documents\test\test.ps1:1 char:1
+ [int]$val = $args[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransforma...
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```